# TextView inputType date in Android - how does it work?

Tags: java, android, date, user-interface, input

I have not found this in any documentation, tutorial or question. Pretty much all tutorials concerned date picker, so I am confused about its functionality.

I have TextView with inputType="date". How do I handle it? Does actually it do anything other than text field does?

What are best practices?

It only has set/get methods for String type. Am I right in assumption that I have to parse contents manually? And if putting in default value, having to format it myself too?

Is there any definition of expected date format? Does it handle Locale differences (mm/dd/yyyy in some, dd/mm/yyyy in other)?

Is there any validation?

Or is it basically "do it yourself" type thing without much convenience?

Comment: you must take it like a String and **after** you can cast it to date or number or what you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

input type date means it will open numeric virtual keyboard on the screen when the user tap the textview. To parse it to your required format, you have to use JAVA date time class.

Comment: Are there any best practices for obtaning locale specific format to use for manual setting/parsing?

Answer (score 0):

Input type simply specifies which kind of keyboard you want the user to use, to simplify the input. For example, a phone number input field does not require letters. Yes, you have to manually parse it, or use helper classes as stated by Mark Henry.

[Textview - inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType)

Comment: That's not the whole truth. android:inputType="datetime" seems to forbid "." although you need it for the date part in Germany...